# XSLT Attribute match is not allowed on this element

Tags: xaml, xslt

I'm getting `Attribute match is not allowed on this element` errors on all these elements XAML except the root. I think I'm missing something about the syntax...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
       <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
               <xsl:output method="html"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">  
            <html>
                <body>
                   <xsl:apply-templates match="/Table"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates match="/Paragraph"/>
                    </body>
            </html>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="Table">
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates match="TableRowGroup"/>
                </table>
            </xsl:template>


            <xsl:template match="TableRowGroup">
                    <xsl:apply-templates match="TableRow"/>
            </xsl:template>


            <xsl:template match="TableRow">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates match="TableCell"/>
                </tr>
            </xsl:template>


            <xsl:template match="TableCell">
                <td>
                </td>
            </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:apply-templates select="..."/>` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates match="..."/>`.

Comment: ty. it works now to some extent, but it ignores the table,.... subelements, just outputting up until `<body>`. a `<xsl:templates>` with any selector give me all the text inside, but the selectors dont work at all

Comment: The `apply-templates` only allows a `select` attribute, not a `match` attribute. So I think as far as the error is concerned my question solves the problem. If you have further problems then post a new question showing the input XML structure, the output you want and the one you currently get. Having both `<xsl:apply-templates match="/Table"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates match="/Paragraph"/>` certainly looks odd or wrong but it is hard to tell what you want without knowing the input XML.